# coloring transparent objects

Tags: graphics

I have problem with ray tracing. I could not put color of the transparent object to the file. Transparent object is seen as white. What is wrong ? Did I forget something in algorithm ?

Note : I could not upload image to stackoverflow because my reputation.

```
trace ( ray ) 
   intersect with objects
   for each light 
       if ( object in shadow )
              colour = black
       else
              diffuse 
              specular
   ambient
   color += trace ( reflect_ray )
   if ( object is transparent )
        color += trace ( transparent_ray )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to directly add the transparent ray, you need to blend it.

```
color = opacity * color + (1 - opacity) * trace( transparent_ray )
```

`opacity` defines how *opaque* the object is. A fully opaque object (`opacity = 1`) is not at all transparent, so the transparent ray will not affect the color. A fully transparent object (`opacity = 0`), such as air, or glass (almost) will not be affected by the object's color, so the color of the ray is just the color of the transparent ray.

Comment: `You don't want to add the transparent ray` I do not understand this sentence. Do you say `You don't want to` **directly** `add the transparent ray`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. i.e. don't just do `color += trace(transparent_ray)`. You need to blend the colors, as I have. I've updated the wording to add "directly". Thanks.

Comment: thanks for replay. Sorry I can not vote up due to low reputation

Comment: Is opacity means how much intensity is lost through material ?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. It's basically the opposite of translucency.